# Increase size of column width in save dialogue short list view

Tags: sapling-addon

our filename conventions are rather long and i can't see and/or edit them in the Blender save dialogue short (or long) list view.

Is there a way to make the columns wider?

Thanks
JK

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the **file display size** to *Large*.
[image: File Display Size]

If you still can't read the labels, you will have to decrease the font size in the User Preferences.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> opens the User Preferences. Then go to the *Themes* rider and change the *Points* value under *Widget Label: Kerning Style*.

[image: Font-Size in User Preferences]

Right clicking on a folder/file item will display its name in the File Name box of the File Browser.

Comment: Thank you. The 'Large' button does exactly what I needed.